# Addthis- incorrect image, meta descriptions being pulled

Tags: facebook, linkedin-api, addthis

I have a problem sharing content directly from my website.  I am using add this and it keeps pulling the incorrect image, link, meta description and meta title through for shares or else jumbles 2 or 3 of them up together. 
A simple example of the incorrect image showing can be found when you share the below links:http://www.matheson.com/news-and-insights/article/matheson-wins-european-law-firm-of-the-year-2015 or 
http://www.matheson.com/news-and-insights/article/matheson-appoints-seven-partners. 
Please note Facebook and LinkedIn are pulling completely different messages/images when I share, both of which are wrong. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I see this issue as well.  I have OG tags twitter tags and all the correct meta tags on my site and when I use AddThis Facebook or linked in, I get the wrong image.  In fact I get different images for each service.  I know it has to do with AddThis because I also use Buffer and buffer is pulling the correct tags.  So I think its an AddThis bug? I used Facebook Debugger and that pulls the correct image. So something strange...

Answer (score 0):

To instruct Facebook and many other services what to show in a share or preview on the Newsfeed, you need to specify Open Graph meta tags.  I would suggest adding the Open Graph tags (og:image, og:description, og:title, and og:url) to each of your pages.

Here's some more information on Open Graph tags:
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381222-optimize-facebook-sharing

Once you add the Open Graph tags, I'd suggest looking at the Facebook Debugger to see if Facebook is reporting any issues:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Matt @ AddThis Support